# Change Background javascript function not working

Tags: javascript

The code (below) seems to compile without any errors, but the "changebackground" function isn't working. it does nothing when you click on it. 
I don't think there is a problem with Syntax, but cant be sure. There are no errors, just no response when i click on the cell. 
"MyClick" works, bu t"ChangeBackground" doesn't.

Any thoughts??

```
<html><body>
<head>
<style>
table,th
{ 
border:1px solid black
font-size:  15px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
empty-cells: show;
}
</style>
<style>
td
{ 
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Arial;
border:1px solid black;
empty-cells: show;
align = "middle;"
}
</style>
<style>
p
{ 
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial;
}
</style>
<style>
a.1{ text-decoration:none;color:WindowText}
</style>
<style>
#header{ display:block;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height: 112px;position:fixed;background-color: #ffffff;border:1px solid #888;}
</style>
<style>
#content{ margin:113px 0px 0px 0px;display:block;border:1px solid #888;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript"> function myClick(args) {    window.clipboardData.setData('text',args.toString());   }</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> function changeBackground() {document.getElementById(cellID).style.borderColor = "2px solid red";   }</script>


</head>
 <p>  Scanned Samples </p> <table></table></div>  <p> Rack: 202771 - _SMEYER_IND_AC_2D-02 </p>

<table> 

<thead> 

<tr> 
 <font size = "10"> </font> 

<th> </th>

<th>1</th>

<th>2</th>

<th>3</th>

<th>4</th>

<th>5</th>

<th>6</th>

<th>7</th>


</tr> 

</thead> 

<td> <font size = "2"><b>A</b></td>

<td><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick="javascript:myClick('202772')"><center>A1<br>0<br>(202772)</center></td>
 <td id = "Cell9"><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick=" javascript:myClick('202780') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell9')"> <center> A2<br>0<br>(202780)</center> </td>

<td id = "Cell17"><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick=" javascript:myClick('202788') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell17')"> <center> A3<br>0<br>(202788)</center> </td>


<td id = "Cell25"><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick=" javascript:myClick('202796') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell25')"> <center> A4<br>0<br>(202796)</center> </td>


<td id = "Cell33"><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick=" javascript:myClick('202804') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell33')"> <center> A5<br>0<br>(202804)</center> </td>


<td id = "Cell41"><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick=" javascript:myClick('202812') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell41')"> <center> A6<br>0<br>(202812)</center> </td>


<td id = "Cell49"><a class = "1" href = "#abcd"onclick=" javascript:myClick('202820') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell49')"> <center> A7<br>0<br>(202820)</center> </td>


</tr>
 </table> 
 </body></html>
```

Comment: `function changeBackground()` accepts no arguments. Try `function changeBackground(cellID)`.

Comment: `<font>`? `<center>`? Inline JavaScript? What is this 1995?

Comment: To be completely honest, this is poor design. Multiple style and script tags,  deprecated HTML tags, too much inline JavaScript. This question was really difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `changeBackground` with parameters when the function definition didn't have it. Here's an example

```
javascript:changeBackground('Cell9')"
```

Here is your function definition

```
function changeBackground() {
    document.getElementById(cellID).style.borderColor = "2px solid red";   
}
```

Try changing that to

```
function changeBackground(cellID) {
    document.getElementById(cellID).style.borderColor = "2px solid red";   
}
```

Also, this is pretty bad form too. You should prefer `stylesheets` over `style` tags, and you have a bunch of them. Same thing with the `script` tags. Please place them in an external JavaScript file.

Also, you are using `inline javascript` too often like this example

```
onclick=" javascript:myClick('202812') "; javascript:changeBackground('Cell41')"
```

This makes the HTML really difficult to read. You should instead use event listeners and place them in your JavaScript file.

Also, the `center` and `font` tags are not supported in HTML5.